# Getting html from asp.net 4.0 web forms without executing the page?

Tags: asp.net, html, webforms, render

I using a pdf component to convert html page to pdf. The issue is when I access the page by url, I am having authorization issues.

In mvc, I can strip the html from view without needing access it by url? Is there anything equivalent in web forms?

Here's how to get html from a view in MVC 3:

```
 using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
            {
                ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(controller.ControllerContext, viewName);
                ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(controller.ControllerContext, viewResult.View, controller.ViewData, controller.TempData, sw);
                viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);

                return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

i had the same issue but i resolved it by calling htmlto pdf on page load if the requested page and it returned as file, try it.

Comment: Would you please be able to provide more details how to get the HTML layout on page load? Thank you.